# Request params not parsed in Ring/Compojure app

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I am writing a web app using Ring and Compojure, and Friend library for authorization. Recently I've made some changes to the project, and now I am not able to fetch request parameters any more.

What I used to do is this:

```
; Routes definition
(defroutes app-routes
  (POST "/*.do" request 
    (insert-data (:params request))))

; Middlewares
(def secured-routes
  (handler/site
    (-> app-routes
        wrap-params
        (friend/authenticate friend-params-map))))
```

and form/URL parameters would be parsed into a Clojure map. Right now this does not seem to work, and `(:params request)` contains maps of the form

```
{:* <request-url>}
```

with a single `:*` key. If I try to `(println request)`, a get a Clojure map with lots of key-value pairs, among which there are

```
:body #object[org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP 0x6ef9a9e1 HttpInputOverHTTP@6ef9a9e1]
```

that seem to contain request data, correct? But how do I fetch those?

Previously I was just using `wrap-params` middleware as described above, and it worked.

One approach that works is invoking `(body-string request)` in each handler, that will return a stringified version of request body. But it would be great to get an automatically parsed Clojure map for each url handler. Obviously, I'm missing something.

Can someone please advise? I would also be happy to find out more how to debug those kinds of handler issues myself - meaning, debug middleware chains and find out why `wrap-params` does not get invoked or is invoked improperly.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** per @nberger's comment, i've tried changing `secured-routes` definition to this:

```
(def secured-routes
  (-> app-routes
      (wrap-defaults site-defaults)
      (friend/authenticate friend-params-map)))
```

but now the login page does not work at all (authentication stopped working). After moving `wrap-defaults` after `friend/authenticate` as suggested in the comment, Friend complains in big font about Invalid anti-forgery token (???)

Comment: Have you tried removing the `friend/authenticate` middleware? You could also remove the explicit `wrap-params` as compojure.handler/site already includes it. It would be great to have a minimal example. By the way, compojure.handler is deprecated, you might want to use [ring-defaults](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-defaults)

Comment: Thank you for comment. I've updated the original question. I didn't know that `handler/site` was deprecated.

Comment: `friend-authenticate` has to be wrapped by `wrap-defaults`, because it assumes the params are already in `form-params` or in `params`, so you should have: `(-> app-routes (wrap-defaults site-defaults) (friend/authenticate friend-params-map))`

Comment: Sorry, you should have: `(-> app-routes (friend/authenticate friend-params-map) (wrap-defaults site-defaults))`

Comment: Thanks for helping out! Updated main post again.

Comment: ring-defaults include anti-forgery protection by default. You should normally use it, but if you want to disable it you can use `(wrap-defaults (assoc-in site-defaults [:security :anti-forgery] false))` instead of just `(wrap-defaults site-defaults)`. See [the readme](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-defaults#customizing) for all the options

Comment: @nberger - thank you, it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the issue. In the front-end code, `POST`s to *.do have been modified to send `application/json` content-type. Below is the jQuery's ajax call that was used:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: '/saveInput.do',
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  data: JSON.stringify(formValues),
});
```

I've modified it to

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: '/saveInput.do',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formValues,
});
```

and it works now. Moreover, original Ajax call with JSON content-type can be preserved by including `wrap-json-params` middleware from [ring-json](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-json), so that routes definition finally becomes:

```
(def secured-routes
  (-> app-routes
      (friend/authenticate friend-params-map)
      (wrap-defaults (assoc-in site-defaults [:security :anti-forgery] false))
      wrap-json-params))
```

I've opted for the latter.
@nberger - thank you for help!